# Azure Devops deploy Yaml to OpenShift

Tags: azure-devops, openshift

I am Having a Yaml Deployment Config to deploy Image to OpenShift.
It contains reference to Docker Image in Artifactory.
It contains service connection and route information.

Usually I do the deployment from the OpenShift web console from Add to Project--->Import Yaml Json

Now I would like to have this done from Azure Devops pipeline.

Is there any way I could execute this Yaml file deployment  from one of the task in Azure devops ?

Or if I first import this YAML from OpenShift web console is there any way further I can handle tagging of images in future releases from the Azure pipeline ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can install the extension [OpenShift Extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=redhat.openshift-vsts), this Azure DevOps extension offers tasks for integrating OpenShift into your build and release pipelines, for example by executing user defined oc commands.

You can refer to the [blog](https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2019/12/05/introduction-to-the-red-hat-openshift-deployment-extension-for-microsoft-azure-devops/) and [doc](https://github.com/redhat-developer/openshift-vsts/blob/master/docs/getting-started.md) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

I work for Red Hat and have found there are a few ways to work Azure DevOps with OpenShift. 3 Patterns I have found OpenShift Extension, Kubernetes/Helm tasks or a self hosted agent running in a pod within openshift that has the oc tool which can help orchestrate.

I've made a video with an overview of 3 Patterns here : https://youtu.be/hMsvN7ld7E8

Comment: When linking to your own site or content (or content that you are affiliated with), you [must disclose your affiliation _in the answer_](/help/promotion) in order for it not to be considered spam. Having the same text in your username as the URL or mentioning it in your profile is not considered sufficient disclosure under Stack Exchange policy.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30542329)